# SQL Query to verify website link

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL table with a column that has various url links. Does anyone know of a query/function/etc. that would loop through each row and validate or verify the link still works. I'm having some issues where some urls within my table still work, others give me a 404.

Comment: I think there is no such function (and should not be as this is not the purpose of databases) available in any database. You can create maybe a script or application may be in java or c# or  some other language of your liking to fetch data from database and do the checks.

Comment: Can you provide a little more context? Do you need a way to keep the table up-to-date with only working URL's? (In that case use a cronjob script that checks them all at set intervals and removes the non-working ones.)

Comment: @Phillip Im looking for a way to see if the urls within my table are still good. My table has a column labeled URL and there is about 2k records in there. I didn't think there was anything in SQL for that but wanted to ask around before looking at a php or java solution.

Comment: This sounds like a pretty simple CLR procedure to write. Just create an HTML request for each URL value found.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done purely from SQL however, it can be done with scripts (which I recommend to be a routine service). The following serves as a mysql + php example. Keep in mind that this is not production code and I wrote it very quickly just to give you an idea of how this can be achieved.

```
<?php
    /* Database Connection Config */
    $db_host        =   '127.0.0.1';
    $db_user        =   'your_username';
    $db_password    =   'your_password';
    $db             =   'your_database';

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db",$db_user,$db_password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    /* Pull all URLS in table. */
    $query = 'SELECT url_id, url FROM url_table';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rc = $stmt->rowCount();
    if($rc > 0) {
        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            /* If url returns 404. */
            if(!is_url_valid($url)) {
                delete_url($row['url_id']);
            }
        }
    }

    function delete_url($url_id) {
        global $conn;
        $query = 'DELETE from url_table WHERE url_id = '.$url_id;
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
        $rc = $stmt->rowCount();
        return $rc;
    }

    /* Returns true/false */
    function is_url_valid($url) {
        $handle = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $response = curl_exec($handle);
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if($httpCode == 404) {
            $status = false;
        } else {
            $status = true;
        }
        curl_close($handle);
        return $status;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use SQL Server for this; I would use Excel & VBA.

Function DoesHTTPFileExist(ByVal inlink As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink (inlink)
    DoesHTTPFileExist = Err.Number = 0
End Function

[image]